# XML file too large to open- need to pull data in Flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I have a 551MB XML file containing data that I want to pull, using a pre-determined parameter and search various instances under that.

For example (Not my actual use but easier to describe and same principle), I have a country name decided in my code, my XML file has a list of countries and their capitals, I search with the country name and pull out the capital city name.

My file is in .XML format and I am unable to open it anywhere, with Xfile, VSCode, Excel etc, presumably due to its size.

I have tried putting it straight into my file `lib` but it can't open with the following error

```
    Unable to open 'file.xml': Invalid string length.
```

Any ideas on how to get about this so that I can call a search on the XML doc in my Flutter VSCode environment?

Thank you

Comment: You can download **Lister** here: https://www.ghisler.com/lister/ It will allow you to open and search inside files of any size.

Comment: Well, you could open it with a real program on a real computer (not a mobile device) and change it's format to something not as oversized as XML. XML was designed to be easily and efficiently packed. It it a huge waste of bytes unpacked. So, maybe get your data from it in advance to make the file smaller that you want to access in your app.

Comment: @nvoigt I am not not using a mobile device? I am using a computer to open it but the usual programs I use crash upon starting to open it. Could I transfer it to Json?

Comment: MS SQL Server SSIS can easily process GB size XML files.